# Why does ajax function in jquery plugin always return 404 Not Found?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a form (contact form 7) to send data to an email. I set up and it runs okay (via Google SMTP). I am using Wordpress framework.

But I want to custom some outputs and response messages. So I decided to use the jquery validation plugin and using the ajax() function in the jquery plugin.

In the ajax() function, I use the serialized data (get from my contact-form-7 form), and url (get from contact-form-7 action attribute) and send them to server (localhost).

And everything works ok (receiving email perfectly) except one thing: ajax() always receives the message: 404 Not Found.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send-message-a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#contactus-form').validate({
            rules: {
                name: "required"
            }, 
            errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        if($('#contactus-form').valid()) {
            var dataSerialize = $('#contactus-form').serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: $('#contactus-form').attr('method'),
                url: $('#contactus-form').attr('action'),
                data: dataSerialize,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Success Ajax');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error Ajax');
                },
                complete: function(xhr, data) {
                    alert('Complete Ajax');
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('Invalid!');
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas to help me?
Thank you.

Comment: What's in here: `$('#contactus-form').attr('action')`?

Comment: `404 Not Found` means url doesn't exists. Check if the url is present/accessible or not. 
Check if `$('#contactus-form').attr('action')` contains the correct URL value.

Comment: $('#contactus-form').attr('action') is my action url. And It exits and runs ok.